# Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему этот код иногда выводит 1 вместо нужного числа

Tags: c, массивы, математика, олимпиада, теория-чисел

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему этот код иногда выводит 1 вместо нужного числа. Спасибо

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
        int main(){
            int isicc;
            scanf ("%d", &isicc);
               
            isicc = abs(isicc);
            printf ("%d\n", isicc?isicc%9?isicc%9:9:0 );
               
        }
```

Comment: Ну и как это воспроизвестию Укажите те случаи при которых вы всегда получаете не то что ожидаете

Comment: @AzizUmarov суть кода в этом: есть число 12345, сначала сумирует 1+2+3+4+5=15, а затем 1+5=6. Вывести как раз должно число от 1 до 9.

Comment: Для *какого* числа, например?

Comment: @Harry к сожалению не знаю, потому-что тестирую не я, и узнать не могу

Comment: А где в коде суммирование? Или взятие остатка от деления числа на 9 это алгоритмический трюк дающий нужный результат?

Comment: @nevilad Да, взятие остатка от деления числа на 9 дает нужный результат, но иногда не работает, почему-то

Comment: У вас какие ограничения на значения чисел? Может, там 30-значные числа, тогда надо работать иначе. Дайте **ТОЧНОЕ** условие задачи, а не ваш его пересказ.

Comment: @Harry Ввод может быть только натуральное число.
Впоследствии подсчитываются все цифры этого натурального числа.
Если эта сумма НЕ является однозначным числом, метод повторяется.
На выходе получается однозначное число.
Возьмем пример:

При входе получаем номер 165 . Методом MM вычисляем каждую цифру (1 + 6 + 5) . Результат - 12 . Поскольку 12 - двузначное число, мы снова вызываем метод MM (1 + 2) . Результатом является число 3 , которое представляет собой одну цифру, поэтому мы можем завершить метод.

Comment: @Harry CPU Time limit: 1 second

Comment: **КАКИЕ ОГРАНИЧЕНИЯ** на натуральные числа? Кстати, раз натуральное - abs не нужно, и проверка на 0 лишняя. 12446241643614234142341642 - натуральное? Вы же откуда-то взяли условие? Так напишите его

Comment: Ограничений нет

Comment: Число 1 допустимый остаток от деления на 9, верно?

Comment: Вам надо суммировать все цифры, а потом делать так, как вы делали.

Comment: @Harry С 17 значным числом уже не работает как надо. Спасибо за ответы

Comment: Потому что вы начали выяснять, как держать микроскоп, не поясняя, что вам нужно забить гвоздь...

Comment: @Harry извините за неудобства

Comment: Дело не в неудобствах, а в том, что без точного ТЗ обычно получается ХЗ. Помнится, был вопрос, который натолкнул на очень эффективное решение после того, как автор dctuj лишь добавил то, что не писал почему-то ранее: "работает для чисел до 10^9". Вот и у вас - вы не озаботились указать точное задание, начали решать через `scanf` - т.е. получалось, что вы вроде как точно знаете, что делаете...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    int s = 0, c;
    while((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && isdigit(c))
        s += c - '0';
    printf ("%d\n", s%9 ? s%9 : 9 );
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!!